# Re-using a query result in a PL/SQL package

Tags: oracle

I have some trouble writing SQL queries. Inside a package function, I am trying to reuse the result of a query in two other queries. Here's how it goes :

My schema stores Requests. Each Request concerns multiple destinations. Also, each Request is detailed in another table (Request_Detail). In addition, Requests are identified by their Ids.

So, I am using mainly 3 tables. One for Requests, another for the destinations and the last one for the details. Each one of theses tables is indexed by the Request_Id column.

The query I want to optimize is when a user wants to find all requests, plus their destinations and commands that have been sent between two dates.

I want to query the Request_Table first in order to get all Request_ids. Then, use this Request_Ids list to query the Command table and the Destination one.

I couldn't find how to do that... I can't use ref cursors as they can't be fetched twice... I just need some array-like or column-like variable to store the Request_Ids, then use this variable twice or more...

Here's the original queries I would like to optimize :

```
    FUNCTION EXTRACT_REQUEST_WITH_DATE (ze_from_date DATE, ze_to_date DATE, x_request_list OUT cursor_type, x_destination_list OUT cursor_type,
                                        x_command_list OUT cursor_type) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

        my_function_id  VARCHAR2(80) := PACKAGE_ID || '.EXTRACT_REQUEST_WITH_DATE';
        my_return_code  VARCHAR2(2);
    BEGIN


        OPEN x_request_list FOR
        SELECT NAME,DESTINATION_TYPE, 
        SUCCESS_CNT, STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
        REQUEST_ID, PARENT_REQUEST_ID, DEDUPLICATION_ID, SUBMIT_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE
        FROM APP_DB.REQUEST_TABLE
        WHERE SUBMIT_DATE >= ze_from_date
            AND SUBMIT_DATE < ze_to_date
        ORDER BY REQUEST_ID;

        OPEN x_destination_list FOR
        SELECT REQUEST_ID, DESTINATION_ID
        FROM APP_DB.DESTINATION_TABLE
        WHERE SUBMIT_DATE >= ze_from_date
            AND SUBMIT_DATE < ze_to_date
        ORDER BY REQUEST_ID;


        OPEN x_command_list FOR
        SELECT SEQUENCE_NUMBER, NAME, PARAMS, DESTINATION_ID 
        SEND_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,PROCESS_CNT, STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
        VALIDITY_PERIOD, TO_ABORT_FLAG 
        FROM APP_DB.REQUEST_DETAILS_TABLE
        WHERE SUBMIT_DATE >= ze_from_date
            AND SUBMIT_DATE < ze_to_date
        ORDER BY REQUEST_ID, DESTINATION_ID, SEQUENCE_NUMBER;

        return RETURN_OK;

    END EXTRACT_REQUEST_WITH_DATE;
```

As you see, we use the same predicate (that is the SUBMIT_DATE conditions) for all 3 queries. I think there's maybe some way to optimize it by getting REQUEST_IDs then using them in the remaining queries.

Thanks for hearing me out !

Comment: Can you post your original query you are trying to optimize? You can optimize original query instead of creating functions. If you still want to use separate function check Oracle Pipeline functions

Comment: Just did. I am in fact using one function for all this. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you really have three different result sets you care about, or do you only really need one result set?

Comment: I do need 3 different sets mainly because of the nature of the details given by the last table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...
I found this method that seems to be efficient enough :

First, defining  **global**  types to use as arrays. Here's the code :

Object(Record) type :

```
create or replace 
TYPE "GENERIC_ID" IS OBJECT(ID VARCHAR2(64));
```

Variable size array of GENERIC_ID

```
create or replace 
TYPE "GENERIC_ID_ARRAY" IS TABLE OF "GENERIC_ID";
```

Then, populating is done via extend() in a FOR LOOP. The resulting array can be used as a table in SQL requests, using :

```
TABLE(CAST(my_array_of_ids AS GENERIC_ID_ARRAY)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Based on the queries you posted I'd just add a `SUBMIT_DATE` index to `REQUEST_TABLE`, `DESTINATION_TABLE` and `REQUEST_DETAILS_TABLE` and leave your SQL as is. All three queries will be optimized and will run just as fast as matching against a table of `REQUEST_ID` values.

Comment: That would help I think. But, I tend to avoid creating too much indexes as the database is already heavily queried. Adding 3 more indexes would make my application slower. 
Also, the query could have been on a field other than the SUBMIT_DATE. 
STATUS, for example isn't present in the DESTINATION_TABLE. This case would force me to get all REQUEST_IDs whom the requests have that status.

Comment: I agree - since you have to query by other values, indexes aren't the right solution. In that case I'd recommend the pipeline solution that @rs suggested above. That's not a strength of mine so I'm afraid I can't be of much help, but you'll find plenty of examples online. Good luck :)

Comment: You're welcome! It also occurred to me that a temporary table might be easier than pipelining. I've never used them, but they may be worth looking into. Again, good luck :)